# Pythonic approach to internal API for strings

Tags: python, json, abstract-class, constants, readonly-attribute

## Question

Is there a "pythonic" (i.e. canonical, official, PEP8-approved, etc) way to re-use string literals in `python` internal (and external) APIs?

---

## Background

For example, I'm working with some (inconsistent) JSON-handling code (thousands of lines) where there are various JSON "`struct`s" we assemble, parse, etc. One of the recurring problems that comes up during code reviews is different JSON `struct`s that use the same internal parameter names, causing confusion and eventually causing bugs to arise, e.g.:

```
pathPacket['src'] = "/tmp"
pathPacket['dst'] = "/home/user/out"
urlPacket['src'] = "localhost"
urlPacket['dst'] = "contoso"
```

These two (example) packets that have dozens of identically named fields, but they represent very different types of data. There was no code-reuse justification for this implementation. People typically use code-completion engines to get the members of the JSON `struct`, and this eventually leads to hard-to-debug problems down the road due to mis-typed string literals causing functional issues, and not triggering an error earlier on. When we have to change these APIs, it takes a lot of time to hunt down the string literals to find out which JSON `struct`s use which fields.

---

## Question - Redux

Is there a better approach to this that is common amongst members of the `python` community? If I was doing this in `C++`, the earlier example would be something like:

```
const char *JSON_PATH_SRC = "src";
const char *JSON_PATH_DST = "dst";
const char *JSON_URL_SRC = "src";
const char *JSON_URL_DST = "dst";
// Define/allocate JSON structs
pathPacket[JSON_PATH_SRC] = "/tmp";
pathPacket[JSON_PATH_DST] = "/home/user/out";
urlPacket[JSON_URL_SRC] = "localhost";
urlPacket[JSON_URL_SRC] = "contoso";
```

My initial approach would be to:

- Use `abc` to make an abstract base class that **can't be initialized as an object**, and populate it with **read-only** constants.
- Use that class as a common module throughout my project.
- By using these constants, I can reduce the chance of a monkey-patching error as the symbols won't exist if mis-spelled, whereas a string literal typo can slip through code reviews.

---

## My Proposed Solution (open to advice/criticism)

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Custom_Structure:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @property
    def JSON_PATH_SRC():
        return self._JSON_PATH_SRC

    @property
    def JSON_PATH_DST():
        return self._JSON_PATH_DST

    @property
    def JSON_URL_SRC():
        return self._JSON_URL_SRC

    @property
    def JSON_URL_DST():
        return self._JSON_URL_DST
```

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh the question is how to best replace literals with constants.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh. It's about enums, not really interning strings

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah thanks, sorry, I misread the question then.

Comment: @MadPhysicist enums would work for the example posed, but possibly not for all the places these strings get used. The c++ example furthers this using const rather than an enum type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this is normally done is:

```
JSON_PATH_SRC = "src"
JSON_PATH_DST = "dst"
JSON_URL_SRC = "src"
JSON_URL_DST = "dst"


pathPacket[JSON_PATH_SRC] = "/tmp"
pathPacket[JSON_PATH_DST] = "/home/user/out"
urlPacket[JSON_URL_SRC] = "localhost"
urlPacket[JSON_URL_SRC] = "contoso"
```

Upper-case to denote "constants" is the way it goes. You'll see this in the standard library, and it's even recommended in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants):

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all
>   capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include
>   `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

Python doesn't have true constants, and it seems to have survived without them. If it makes you feel more comfortable wrapping this in a class that uses `ABCmeta` with properties, go ahead. Indeed, I'm pretty sure `abc.ABCmeta` doesn't *not* prevent object initialization. Indeed, if it *did*, your use of `property` would not work! `property` objects *belong to the class*, but are meant to be accessed from an instance. To me, it just looks like a lot of rigamarole for very little gain.

Comment: You could stick your constants into a separate module and use that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sure.

Comment: you could even have a swappable module to select groups of constants similar to how localization is often done..

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way in my opinion to make constants is just to set them as variables in your module (and not modify them).

```
JSON_PATH_SRC = "src"
JSON_PATH_DST = "dst"
JSON_URL_SRC = "src"
JSON_URL_DST = "dst"
```

Then if you need to reference them from another module they're already namespaced for you.

```
>>> that_module.JSON_PATH_SRC
'src'
>>> that_module.JSON_PATH_DST
'dst'
>>> that_module.JSON_URL_SRC
'src'
>>> that_module.JSON_URL_DST
'dst'
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create a bunch of constants is to place them into a module, and import them as necessary. For example, you could have a `constants.py` module with

```
JSON_PATH_SRC = "src"
JSON_PATH_DST = "dst"
JSON_URL_SRC = "src"
JSON_URL_DST = "dst"
```

Your code would then do something like

```
from constants import JSON_URL_SRC
...
urlPacket[JSON_URL_SRC] = "localhost"
```

If you would like a better defined grouping of the constants, you can either stick them into separate modules in a dedicated package, allowing you to access them like `constants.json.url.DST` for example, or you could use [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)s. The `Enum` class allows you to group related sets of constants into a single namespace. You could write a module `constants.py` like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class JSONPath(Enum):
    SRC = 'src'
    DST = 'dst'

class JSONUrl(Enum):
    SRC = 'src'
    DST = 'dst'
```

OR

```
from enum import Enum

class JSON(Enum):
    PATH_SRC = 'src'
    PATH_DST = 'dst'
    URL_SRC = 'src'
    URL_DST = 'dst'
```

How exactly you separate your constants is up to you. You can have a single giant enum, one per category or something in between. You would access the in your code like this:

```
from constants import JSONURL
...
urlPacket[JSONURL.SRC.value] = "localhost"
```

OR

```
from constants import JSON
...
urlPacket[JSON.URL_SRC.value] = "localhost"
```